# How to set custom user id for anonymous FirebaseUser in Unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, unity3d-editor

I am using Unity 5.5.2f1 and Firebase 3.0.0 plugin.
How can I set custom user Id for logged in anonymous user?
The user id is always different when app starts in editor and `Auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()` is calld and it gives me user ids like this:

```
LNLFDXFIRC
NPLJVRVIPY
NQDUXWFNFO
OEJUVPVABO
PGGXRPNRVY
PHQGHUMEAY
STMWCYSYYC
VSCXGGBWKF
XTLSGYPSFA
ZNIMKKASVW
ZVSRTKJPRE
```

I have tried this method before and also after login:

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorAuthUserId(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier);
```

but it does not change logged in user's userId.
There is lack of documentation, does anybody know how to do it?